# Persisting Deserialized objects error in Symfony2

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity object with properties `id` and `trucknr`. I place a few data and then query for all. 
I use JMS SerializerBundle to serialize this to JSON and I'm using `file_put_contents` to export that to a JSON file, then I use `deserialize` to read my JSON file, and it deserializes fine. 
I use:

```
$read = $serializer->deserialize($file,'ArrayCollection<App\TestBundle\Entity\Truck>','json');
```

The problem is when I'm trying to persist this to my database. For that I used:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->merge($read);
$em->flush();
```

I get this error:

```
EntityManager#merge() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.
```

when I run `dump_var` on `$read` I get an array collection of three rows:

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(App\TestBundle\Entity\Truck)#767 (2) { ["id":protected]=> NULL ["trucks_nr":protected]=> string(4) "1243" } 
[1]=> object(App\TestBundle\Entity\Truck)#782 (2) { ["id":protected]=> NULL ["trucks_nr":protected]=> string(4) "3245" } 
[2]=> object(App\TestBundle\Entity\Truck)#783 (2) { ["id":protected]=> NULL ["trucks_nr":protected]=> string(4) "5622" } }
```

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible. When I'm querying for one row it persists or merges fine. Is it possible to persist an array collection of objects, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deserialize an array of entities which you need to loop through so they can be merged properly:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
for ($i = count($read) -1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $em->merge($read[$i]);
}
$em->flush();
```

[edit] Not sure if you really want to use `merge()` as your deserialized entities don't seem to be detached but rather new ones (as they've got no `id`)? In this case you need to call `persist()` instead.

Comment: ive been playing around with merge and persist. i actually want to update the entites based on a unique field. so if my field was already used it should merge and if not it should update. i tested with ids If i serialize it with id and use merge it updates those used ids with my new values. but if my json has new ids and used ids i get an error when i use merge. and persist seems to create new objects.